# What would the Best move for Black be in Algebraic Chess Notation?

Tags: computer-chess, notation

What would the best move for black be in algebraic chess notation?

```
[Title "Black to play and win"]
[fen "7k/1p4p1/p4b1p/3N3P/2p5/2rb4/PP2r3/K2R2R1 b - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rc1+ leads to mate in 2

```
[fen "7k/1p4p1/p4b1p/3N3P/2p5/2rb4/PP2r3/K2R2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rc1+ 2. Rxc1 Bxb2#
```